# Whether rtlib - lotus notes rich text library supports IBM Domino Server 64bit

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm evaluating rtLib library (www.rtlib.com) for analyzing lotus notes richtext fields in documents. 
Would like to know whether anyone has experience on using this library? 
Whether this library supports Domino server 64 bit on Windows 2012 R2?

Tried evaluation version on Domino server 64bit and it keeps on crashing the server

Comment: This question is probably best addressed by the developer of rtlib -- I believe it is Normunds Kalnberzins. You can contact him via a form on his site.  http://www.rtlib.com/site/rtlibhome.nsf/fmBugReport?OpenForm. By the way: you didn't specify whether you are running 64 bit Domino or not. You could be running 32 bit Domino on Win64, and that almost certainly makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you Richard. I am running the library on 64bit Domino server on Windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rtlib since years (Excellent product), and it works on Domino 64/Windows 64 (but not tested on Windows 2012)

64 bits support on Windows starts with version 1.7c

Did you add this in your Notes.ini (on server) :
**LS64BITCCALLOUTPOINTERSUPPORT=1**

Comment: Yes, the ini parameter is already added. The library works on the server for small size documents, any sdocuments with richtext field  greater than 10kb, the server is getting crashed on using the library. The same code works fine on 32 bit notes client machine without any problem

Comment: Works fine on servers with W7 Ultimate 64 bits, or Windows 10 PRO 64 bits, with documents larger than 10kb. Or perhaps are you using some things in the library that I don't? Do you know which Lotusscript statements calling the lib is crashing your server ?

Comment: Thank you so much. While calling the first statement ctx.getRichTextItem doc, "Body", itself the server crashes for big richtext fields